# Speeding-up reads for Linux application

Tags: linux, caching

My program reads a file, interleaving it as below:

[image]

The file to be read is large. It is split into four parts that are then split into many blocks. My program first reads block 1 of part 1, then jumps to block 1 of part 2, and so on. Then back to the block 2 of part 1, ..., as such.

The performance drops in tests. I believe the reason is that the page cache feature of kernel doesn't work efficiently in such situations. But the file is too large to `mmap()`, and the file is located in NFS.

How do I speed up reading in such a situation? Any comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Certainly jumping around the file like you've done is crushing the performance. Is there anyway you can restructure your algorithm to read linearly? Also, is there anyway you can run your code co-located with the box that holds the file, as opposed to pulling the contents across NFS as you are currently doing?

Comment: You say you aren't able to mmap the file, but you are able to read all the data into memory?

Comment: @chrisaycock Unfortunately, I must read and send files as above according to standard. The result of many tests show that NFS is not bottleneck.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato After read data from file into my buffer, I send the data across network, then reuse the buffer. So I don't read all the data into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [`posix_fadvise()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_fadvise.html) to give the system hints on your usage, eg. use `POSIX_FADV_RANDOM` to disable readahead, and possibly use `POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED` to have the system try to read the next block into the page cache before you need it (if you can predict this).
You could also try to use `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` once you are done reading a block to have the system free the underlying cache pages, although this might not be necessary

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, though I didn't adopt it. Use `posix_fadvise()` is complicated, I first generated the file interleaving so as to I can read linearly.

Answer (score 0):

For each pair of blocks, read both in, process the first, and push the second on to a stack. When you come to the end of the file, start shifting values off the bottom of the stack, processing them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can break up the reading into linear chunks.  For example, if your code looks like this:

```
int index = 0;
for (int block=0; block<n_blocks; ++block) {
  for (int part=0; part<n_parts; ++part) {
    seek(file,part*n_blocks+block);
    data[part] = readChar(file);
  }
  send(data);
}
```

change it to this:

```
for (int chunk=0; chunk<n_chunks; ++chunk) {
  for (int part=0; part<n_parts; ++part) {
    seek(file,part*n_blocks+chunk*n_blocks_per_chunk);
    for (int block=0; block<n_blocks_per_chunk; ++block) {
      data[block*n_parts+part] = readChar(file);
    }
  }
  send(data);
}
```

Then optimize n_blocks_per_chunk for your cache.